# OpenGL ground plane becoming black at certain perspectives

Tags: c, opengl, lighting

I have a simple program in OpenGL that creates a ground plane, randomly placed tree objects, and has some lightning. There is an issue with the lightning that I am unable to solve. When the camera at a certain 'x' angle, the lightning seems to be not affecting the ground and it appears black. This an instant change, it does not gradually darken. Most of the ground is lit seemingly fine, but at certain angles it immediately turns black. The code is very messy and a lot of the core of it is part of the OpenGL tutorial on Lighthouse 3D because I am taking a class on OpenGL and this is the goal for the class, to take these tutorials and create something unique with it. Does anyone know how to fix this? Maybe lighting is implemented incorrectly? The code below is the code for drawing the ground plane.

```
// Draw ground
glColor3f(0.039f, 0.341f, 0.078f);
glNormal3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-1500.0f, -8.0f, -1500.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1500.0f, -8.0f,  1500.0f);
    glVertex3f( 1500.0f, -8.0f,  1500.0f);
    glVertex3f( 1500.0f, -8.0f, -1500.0f);
glEnd();
```

This code is for the lighting.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT2);
glEnable(GL_AMBIENT);
glEnable(GL_DIFFUSE);
glEnable(GL_SPECULAR);
glDisable(GL_EMISSION);
GLfloat lightpos[] = {1.0, 1.0, 7.0, 1.0};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightpos);

GLfloat ambientLight[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
GLfloat diffuseLight[] = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8, 1.0f };
GLfloat specularLight[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
GLfloat position[] = { 1250.0f, 1250.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat position2[] = { -1250.0, 1250.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f};
GLfloat position3[] = { 2.0f, 1250.0f, 1250.0f, 1.0f};


glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specularLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, position2);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, specularLight);
//glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_POSITION, position3);
//glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);
//glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseLight);
//glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_SPECULAR, specularLight);
```

Comment: Strange that old OpenGL is still teached. Anyway if you have to learn there is no way around, but i would suggest you (if you are interested in OpenGL) to learn 3.x core and up. Back to your problem did you check if the light is moving under the plane when it becomes black? (that the light is not moving when you move your camera)

Comment: @t.niese Unfortunately moving the lighting up along the Y coordinate did not fix it. The light is also in one static position so I am really unsure of what the problem is. Thanks though!

Comment: Sorry i have formulated it wrong. I wanted to know if you are sure that your light position is in world-space like your plane? Moving the camera is done by changing the view-matrix. If you don't do that the same way to the light then it is similar as if the light is fixed to the camera by an imaginary stick. So the light would move relative to the camera. But without knowing more of your code it is hard to guess. But most likely this is the problem. check this probably it will help you http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/168706-Light-Position-in-eye-s-cordinate